# Using JQuery Plugins With Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I've got a JQuery plugin (mixItUp) that I'm trying to use with Typescript, which doesn't have it's own *.d.ts file.

How can I make it work with typescript?

I've made my own mixItUp.d.tds file with the following content:

```
interface JQuery
{
    mixItUp():any;
}
```

In the module that I'm trying to use mixItUp in, I am using the following code:

```
$('#mySelector').mixItUp();
```

It compiles fine, and I get intellisense for mixItUp, so somehow it's picked up the mixItUp.d.ts file without me referencing it.

In the html, I'm loading in jquery, then the non-typescript (Pure js) mixItUp library before this module, so I know both jquery and mixitup really exists at that point in time.

However, when I load the page I get the following error message:

```
$(...).mixItUp is not a function(…)
```

Most of the guides I'm finding seem to be using what I understand to be the old way of referencing *.d.ts files.

Can someone please explain the correct way to use JQuery plugins with typescript, as well as if possible how to reference non typescript libraries (I assume the technique will be similar).

Thanks.

Comment: Is the mixItUp javascript file on the page?

Comment: @Radio- yes it is.  I've edited my question to make it clear that that was the "Pure js" library I was referring to.

Comment: not sure if this helps, see if you can repro your problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/dmqr7szq/

Answer (score 0):

If it's happening at runtime, it's most likely not caused by Typescript, since TS just gets compiled to JS. Since TS itself has no knowledge of your library and only gets fed the information about it by your interface, it compiles that call as-is(which can be proven, by just looking at the output in the Developer console or similar).

So make sure mixItUp is loaded correctly, before your code is executed(but after jQuery) and it should work fine(given that the jQuery version you're using is supported by the plugin)

Comment: if I place the line $('#mySelector').mixItUp(); directly on the page, it loads up fine, however when I comment that out and uncomment the one in my .ts file I get the error.
Perhaps if someone could explain how to generally bring in/reference a non-typescript library, that might lead be to the answer?

Comment: There are a lot of factors that could influence the outcome here. It would be good if you could provide more information on how you build TS and then include the JS File on your Page. The contents of the page(or at least the part where the JS files are included), would also help.

Comment: Generally there is no magic to do when adding JS libraries to TS files. Actually you don't even need to do anything special. TS compiles to JS and is fully compatible with it. You can add self-made typings to your project(like you did) to get the benefit of code completion and compile time checking if your code is using the library right. Other than that, it's completely optional.

Comment: the .ts files are bundled together via browserify within a gulp build process, which outputs a single app.js file for my js, the same is done for vendor typescript files, with an output of vendor.js.
On the html page I put a script tag for vendor.js, then a script tag for the mixItUp library, then finally a script tag for my app.js file.

It seems like mixItUp just isn't properly hooking up to JQuery from within the .ts file, but works fine when I try to do it outside of a module (Just in a script tag).

Comment: From the information you provided I don't see why it's not working to be honest. The jQuery you're using in the TS file is the same you're using in the script tags(or at least should be. It might not be if, for some reason, another version is loaded after loading mixItUp). Be sure to check if some of the libraries you're using doesn't already include jQuery.

Comment: hmm, it is strange.
Can you point me to any working example of using a jquery plugin with typescript, you'd think there would be many examples, but I can only find a handful, and they're all using the old style of referencing (e.g. ///reference etc)

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry. jQuery is rarely used directly(or should be rarely used directly), because most people use frameworks like angular, which wrap it. You can call $.fn.jquery in the console check if the version matches. If it doesn't you know for sure that some other version is loaded.  Still, it might help if you include more code(what libraries you include, the file in which you use jQuery. Things like that)